# msi mag x570 tomahawk AMD Raid array gone after BIOS update

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid-1

I went through and installed newest BIOS (7C84v15), chipset driver and other drivers form MSI website. Because I had problems with my system stability. Upon restarting my PC I noticed that one of my drives is gone.

I had 2 HDDs setup in RAID 1 array. I’ve done it via BIOS with RAIDXpert2. Now when I go there under Array Management I can only see my boot NvME Drive (third illustration). The array is made from two 1TB Toshiba HDWD110. The drives are visible in Windows disk management tool as two separate drives with anonymus partition (Dysk 0 and Dysk 1 in picture below) and in BIOS system status.

I tried to install [AMD RAID Installer](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-am4/x570) but it won't go through.

Is there a way to recover the array?

My system: Windows 10 64b, AMD Ryzen 9 5950x, MSI mag x570 tomahawk Wi-Fi

[Disks Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUuPj.jpg)

[BIOS System Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wje5X.jpg)

[BIOS Array Proporties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSpbO.jpg)

Edit: Because of lack of better option I formatted one of the drives and then used Recuva to recover most of the data.

Comment: You should avoid any disk operations unless you have a disk image of both disks.  RAID 0 allows for zero drive failures. What is troubling about your problem is that the RAIDXpert2 didn't detect your drives.  I wish you came to us before you updated your firmware, there are typically things you must do, before you do a firmware when using a RAID.

Comment: Well I'm a noob in this regards. I've read the manual of my motherboard so I though I was set to go :C

Comment: Had you asked the question and mentioned the fact you were using RAIDXpert2 in a RAID 0 configuration, I would have suggested a firmware update, but only after you performed a backup of your data. One of the things that happen is your settings were lost, so I would have also, had you perform a backup of the firmware settings.

Comment: I did not and I made RAID 1 array. Can I just re partition (With Windows) one drive and have my data back (As the 2 drives should be mirrored)?

Comment: I apologize for some reason my brain thought you were using RAID 0.  My advice doesn't really change, the RAID should not be modified outside of RAIDXpert2, otherwise you risk all data on the disk.

Comment: Do you mean the RAIDXpert2 in the BIOS or the Windows app? Cause I don't have access to the second one. And the first one is not even recognising the hard drives.

Comment: You indicated RAIDXpert2 was a feature of the firmware not an application running on Windows.

Comment: So if I cannot see the array in RAIDXpert2 then what shall I do?